# Apache not connecting to local area network. After IP changes

Tags: apache, networking

My apache stopped handling LAN requests after router had hard restart and that caused Local IP addresses to be reassigned via DHCP. I tried to re-config my PC so it would use old IP, how ever, it doesn't connect anymore.

I'm not really certain where to start debugging.

Pinging to my IP trough LAN sources is fine, the host is reachable.

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Setting for Listening on httpd.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Comment: Could you share the error when you're trying to connect to the host?

Comment: @IgorServulo Apache access log and error log doesnt really provide me with any info about it. Browser itself says that This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by reinstalling the wamp, for some reason it loses its configs somewhere in between, so reinstalling refreshes it.